# How can I create this statistical symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I want to reproduce this equation, but I don't know how to make the highlighted symbol. I checked the Comprehensive LaTeX symbols manual, but couldn't find a similar one.

[image]

Comment: maybe `\mathds{I}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbbm{I}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]